# How can I divide an interval into increasing/decreasing chirp-like lengths (MatlabR2014b)?

Tags: matlab

I understand how to divide a given interval in 'N' equal subintervals.

```
min_range=a;
max_range=b;
intervalcount=N;
x = (b-a)/N;
y=min_range:x:max_range
```

But how do I get 'N' intervals of varying length. I found a related post 
[How to divide time interval into parts of varying length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44419487/how-to-divide-time-interval-into-parts-of-varying-length) but this solution is for the case of repetitive sequence of interval length.

I am looking for a solution that returns best 'N' partitions of increasing length for a given range i-e **length(interval_x) < length(interval_(x+1))**.
The resulting subintervals will be *chirp*-like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement that each interval has to be larger than the last makes it a little open-ended, since there are a number of different ways to satisfy that constraint. One option is to make each interval be a fixed increment larger than the last (i.e. interval one is width `w`, interval two is width `2*w`, etc.). Here's an easy way to accomplish this is with [`cumsum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html):

```
v = cumsum(0:N);
y = a+(b-a).*v./v(end);
```